# Как сформировать список списков Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать список списков в Python для следующего набора списков:

```
name = ['John']
sname = ['Black']
money = ['10', '20', '15']
car = ['red', 'blue', 'white']
car_num = ['221', '152', '612154']
```

Чтобы получить таблицу вида:

```
--------------------------------------
name | sname | money| car  | car_num |
-------------------------------------
John | Black | 10   | red  | 221     |
     |       | 20   | blue | 152     |
     |       | 15   | white| 612154  |
--------------------------------------
```

Т.е. чтобы появился список с этими данными, который можно записать в csv файл при помощи команды пандаса:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name","sname","money","car","car_num"])
```

В списке name и sname всегда будет по 1 элементу, который будет состоять из нескольких слов. К примеру за место John будет записано

```
 name = ['John from NewYork']
```

В списках money, car, car_num всегда будет равное количество элементов, до 40 шт. (в примере всего лишь 3 накидал) 
Так же подскажите пожалуйста как потом сие чудо сохранить в csv, чтобы по итогу появилась таблица из примера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите:

- находим максимальную длину списков
- добиваем пустыми строками до нужной длины те списки, которые могут быть недостаточно длинными (иначе `Pandas` будет ругаться, что это неправильная таблица)

Хотя не очень понятно, зачем вам один элемент на весь столбец таблицы. Разве что для красоты.

```
import pandas as pd

name = ['John from NewYork']
sname = ['Black']
money = ['10', '20', '15']
car = ['red', 'blue', 'white']
car_num = ['221', '152', '612154']

max_len = max(map(len, [name, sname, money, car, car_num]))
pad_list = lambda x,n: x + [''] * (n - len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': pad_list(name, max_len),
    'sname': pad_list(sname, max_len),
    'money': money,
    'car': car,
    'car_num': car_num, 
})

df
```

Вывод:

```
                 name   sname   money     car   car_num
0   John from NewYork   Black      10     red       221
1                                  20    blue       152
2                                  15   white    612154
```

Comment: Можете подсказать из-за чего в csv записываются не данные из переменных, а то что находится в кавычках в df 'name' и т.д.

Comment: Я не понял ваш вопрос, уточните детали.  Вы хотите прямо таблицу такую в csv получить? Этот формат не для такого вообще-то

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто не так записал) Вызывал в метод записи просто переменную df, без указания ключей. Уже разобрался, спасибо за ответы